# Galois group of $x^3+x+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to $S_3 $

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

> Let E be splitting field of $x^3+x+1 \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.
>
> Proof that Gal{E/$\mathbb{Q}$}$\cong S_3$. Specify all extension fields L with $\mathbb{Q} \subset L \subset E$ and the degree [L : $\mathbb{Q}$] of the extensions.

Set $f(x):= x^3+x+1 \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$. It's easy to see that f is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

At first, I wanted to determine E. With Cardano formula I got the complex roots

$$x_2 = \sqrt[3]{- \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{31}{108}}} + i \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{31}{108}}}\quad\text{and}\quad x_3 = \sqrt[3]{- \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{31}{108}}} - i \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{31}{108}}}$$

Since f has degree 3, the roots $x_2, x_3$ must be simple. So it exists another real root $x_1$ of f. Therefore we can write $f(x)= (x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$ in $E[x] \Rightarrow f$ is separable and E is splitting field of $f \Rightarrow E/\mathbb{Q}$ is galois.
We got that: $[E:K] = |Gal(E/K)| \Leftrightarrow E/K$ is galois. So $|Gal(E/ \mathbb{Q})| = [E:\mathbb{Q}]$.

Now i don't know how to go on. Can i somehow get the degree of E/$\mathbb{Q}$ by means of $x_1, x_2, x_3$? And how can i easily calculate $x_1$ or isn't that necessary to solve the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810055/galois-groups-of-x3-3x1-and-x3-2x23-over-mathbbq/1812965#1812965) and the article of Keith Conrad [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/cubicquartic.pdf), where he determines the Galois group for all cubic (and quartic) polynomials. Then it is clear how to "go on".

Comment: For the first part, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2809524/589

Comment: Is it possible that the Galois group of a polynomial of degree 3 has cardinality $6$ ?

Comment: @NewMath Yes, $S_3$ has $6$ elements. Please click on the link given by lhf (and read his answer).

Comment: [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) make it particularly easy to find the $n$th zero of a degree $n$ polynomial if you already know $n-1$ of them.

Comment: I think the first thing to see is that if $K$ is the splitting field of $f$ of degree $n$ and $[K:Q] = n!$ then $Gal(K/Q) = S_n$. If $f = x^3+x+1$ is irreducible modulo $2$ then it is irreducible over $Q$ and $3$ divides $[K:Q]$. And if $f$ has a complex root then $2$ divides $[K:Q]$.

Comment: @reuns Can you explain why [K:Q] = n! and 2 divides [K:Q] when complex roots exists?

Comment: Think to $K$ as a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$. If it is not contained in $\mathbb{R}$ then you know a subgroup of $Gal(K/Q)$ of order $2$ : the one generated by the complex conjugaison (exchanging the two complex roots of $f$)

Comment: @reuns Ok thanks!!

Comment: Hint: -31 is not a square in $\Bbb Q$